# Unity post to api empty data

Tags: unity-game-engine

Strange problem.

As of what I read on the internet and 
find in the unity documentation;

This should be the correct way to post from unity to an API server.

```
    // create new form
    formData = new List<IMultipartFormSection>();

    // create param
    formData.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("m_board_id=" + boardId));

    //1. Generate UnityWebRequest (UnityWebRequestを生成)
    UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Post("[my website link]", formData);

    using (request)
    {
        yield return request.SendWebRequest();

        if (request.isHttpError || request.isNetworkError)
        {
            Debug.Log(request.error);                
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("succes");
        }
    }
```

When I do this; the link is executed, but the formData isn't sent with it. 
The data is empty!

When I do a request like this;

```
 UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Post("[my website api link]?m_board_id=" + boardId, formData);
```

It works and the database is updated.
The formData is still empty!

I guess this wouldn't be the right way to execute a post request from unity, right? 
What am I doing wrong here with the formData.Add function?

Anybody that can send me in the right direction?

I would love to learn more about unity.

Thank you in advance.

Wesley

Comment: so.. there are things that we should clarify first.. `UnityWebRequest.Post("[my website link]", formData);` sends the `formData` through [Request Body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_message_body). while `UnityWebRequest.Post("[my website api link]?m_board_id=" + boardId, formData);` sends the `boardId` as [Query String](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).. does the backend actually checks the Request Body? You have stated "*It works and **the database is updated**. The formData is still empty!*". how did you check whether `formData` is sent to the server?

Comment: When I do the first request; it shows a validation error. The second request works as it's send the data in the URL on a post request.